# How to display WordPress archive into three columns

Tags: posts, categories

```
<?php  $cats = get_categories('child_of='.get_query_var('cat')); 

foreach ($cats as $cat) :

$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3, // max number of post per category
'category__in' => array($cat->term_id)
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); 

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    echo '<h3>'.$cat->name.'</h3>';

    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>     
    <?php /*general loop output; for instance: */ ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    <br />  

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : 
    echo 'No Posts for '.$cat->name;                
    endif; 

endforeach; ?>
```

- Here is what I want to have
  [image]

Comment: Make all contents of while loop inside a div and assign these css properties to that div `float:left; width:30%;`.

Comment: What theme are you using? Do you have Bootstrap or Foundation or anything with columns already built in?

Comment: using child theme - "worldwide"

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post here: https://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/ on how to do just that.

The way I use most often is number 3. It's a bit involved, but here are the steps. For more in depth coverage (which you'll probably want), check out the post.

1. Add the my_multi_col_v2 function to your functions.php file

   ```
   function my_multi_col_v2($content){
       // run through a couple of essential tasks to prepare the content
       $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
       $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

       // the first "more" is converted to a span with ID
       $columns = preg_split('/(<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>)|(<!--more-->)<\/p>/', $content);
       $col_count = count($columns);

       if($col_count > 1) {
           for($i=0; $i<$col_count; $i++) {
               // check to see if there is a final </p>, if not add it
               if(!preg_match('/<\/p>\s?$/', $columns[$i]) )  {
                   $columns[$i] .= '</p>';
               }
               // check to see if there is an appending </p>, if there is, remove
               $columns[$i] = preg_replace('/^\s?<\/p>/', '', $columns[$i]);
               // now add the div wrapper
               $columns[$i] = '<div class="dynamic-col-'.($i+1).'">'.$columns[$i].'</div>';
           }
           $content = join($columns, "\n").'<div class="clear"></div>';
       }
       else {
           // this page does not have dynamic columns
           $content = wpautop($content);
       }
       // remove any left over empty <p> tags
       $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content);
       return $content;
       }
   ```
2. Replace your `the_content()` tag in your page template with this:

   ```
   $content = get_the_content('',FALSE,''); // arguments remove 'more' text
   echo my_multi_col_v2($content);
   ```
3. Add some CSS to format the markup into columns

   ```
   /* dynamic columns */
   div.dynamic-col-1 { float: left; width: 38%; padding-right: 2%;}
   div.dynamic-col-2 { float: left; width: 38%;padding-right: 2%;}
   div.dynamic-col-3 { float: left; width: 20%;}
   div.clear { clear: both; }
   ```
4. Remember to add the two `<!--more-->` tags in your post/page content to create the three columns.